# Best practices when implementing CI/CD pipeline using GitHub/Jenkins/Kubernetes

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

This question is more advice related so I hope its not flagged for anything. Just really need help :(

Trying to implement CI/CD using GitHub/Jenkins/Kubernetes.

On a highlevel this is what should happen:

1. Build on Jenkins
2. Push to container registry
3. Deploy built image on Kubernetes development cluster
4. Once testing finished on Development cluster, deploy it on a client
   testing cluster and finally production cluster

So far this is what I have created a job on Jenkins which will be triggered using a Github hook. 
This job is responsible for the following things:

1. Checkout from GitHub
2. Run unit tests / call REST API and send unit test results
3. Build artifacts using maven / call REST API and inform if build
   success or fail
4. Build docker image
5. Push docker image to container registry (docker image will have
   incremented versions which match with the BUILD_NUMBER environment variable)

The above stated tasks are more or less completed and I dont need much assitance with it (unless anyone thinks the aforementioned steps are not best practice)

I do need help with the part where I deploy to the Kubernetes cluster.

For local testing, I have set up a local cluster using Vagrant boxes and it works. In order to deploy the built image on the development cluster, I am thinking about doing it like this:
    Point Jenkins build server to Kubernetes development cluster
    Deploy using deployment.yml and service.yml (available in my repo)
This part I need help with...

Is this wrong practice? Is there a better/easier way to do it?

Also is there a way to migrate between clusters? Ex: Development cluster to client testing cluster and client testing cluster to production cluster etc

When searching on the internet, the name Helm comes up a lot but I am not sure if it will be applicable to my use case. I would test it and see but I am a bit hard pressed for time which is why I cant

Would appreciate any help y'all could provide.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are countless ways of doing this. Take Helm out for now as you are just starting.

If you are already using Github and docker , then I would just recommend you to push your code/changes/config/Dockerfile to Github that will auto trigger a docker build on Dockerhub ( maybe jenkins in ur case if u dont want to use dockerhub for builds ) , it can be a multi-stage docker build where you can build code , run tests , throw away dev environmenet , and finally produce a producion docker image , once the image is produced , it will triger a web hook to your kubernetes deployment job/manifests to deploy on to test evironmenet , followed by manual triiger to deploy to production.

The docker images can be tagged based on SHA of the commits in Github/Git so that you can deploy and rollback based on commits.

Reference: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/gitops-cloud-build

Here is my Gitlab implementation of Gtips workflow:

```
# Author , IjazAhmad

image: docker:latest

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

services:
  - docker:dind

variables:
  CI_REGISTRY: dockerhub.example.com
  CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY/$CI_PROJECT_PATH
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

before_script:
  - docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY  

docker-build:
  stage: build
  script:
     - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true
     - docker build --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest .

docker-push:
  stage: build
  script:
     - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
     - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest

unit-tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "running unit testson the image"
    - echo "running security testing on the image"
    - echo "pushing the results to build/test pipeline dashboard"


sast:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "running security testing on the image"
    - echo "pushing the results to build/test pipeline dashboard"


dast:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "running security testing on the image"
    - echo "pushing the results to build/test pipeline dashboard"


testing:
  stage: deploy
  script:
     - sed -i "s|CI_IMAGE|$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE|g" k8s-configs/deployment.yaml
     - sed -i "s|TAG|$CI_COMMIT_SHA|g" k8s-configs/deployment.yaml
     - kubectl apply --namespace webproduction-test -f k8s-configs/
  environment:
    name: testing
    url: https://testing.example.com

  only:
    - branches


staging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
     - sed -i "s|CI_IMAGE|$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE|g" k8s-configs/deployment.yaml
     - sed -i "s|TAG|$CI_COMMIT_SHA|g" k8s-configs/deployment.yaml
     - kubectl apply --namespace webproduction-stage -f k8s-configs/
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: https://staging.example.com
  only:
    - master



production:
  stage: deploy
  script:
     - sed -i "s|CI_IMAGE|$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE|g" k8s-configs/deployment.yaml
     - sed -i "s|TAG|$CI_COMMIT_SHA|g" k8s-configs/deployment.yaml
     - kubectl apply --namespace webproduction-prod -f k8s-configs/    
  environment:
    name: production
    url: https://production.example.com
  when: manual
  only:
    - master
```

[image: Pipeline]

Links:

[Trigger Jenkins builds by pushing to Github](https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/trigger-jenkins-builds-pushing-github/)

[Triggering a Jenkins build from a push to Github](https://medium.com/@marc_best/trigger-a-jenkins-build-from-a-github-push-b922468ef1ae)

[Jenkins: Kick off a CI Build with GitHub Push Notifications](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/12/21/jenkins-kick-off-a-ci-build-with-github-push-notifications)

Comment: Thanks! I have a couple of questions tho: How can I deploy to Kubernetes using a Webhook? Is there an API exposed? Also, at a high level could you please explain the best way to deploy to Kubernetes from Jenkins? Thanks again

Comment: The webhook term is used in general. for example u can configure dockerhub to trigger a jenkins job on new image tag arrival , that jenkins job will deploy to kubernetes.

Comment: or you can trigger a jenkins job from github , using github API , the jenkins will build the image , push it to registry and trigger a downstream job that will deploy the new image to kubernetes

Comment: there are countless of permutations :)

Comment: I get it.. Your latter suggestion is what I was planning to implement as well :) If I were to implement it, I would have to point my Jenkins server to my cluster right? As in, I would have to move the `/.kube/config` file on my master node to the `$HOME/.kube/` of my Jenkins server, right

Comment: Just checking to see if I understood it 100%.. A little bit new to this as you might have guessed :)

Comment: yes , there are multiple ways of doing that again , many permutations , upload kubeconfig file to jenkins , or store it as credential , or use kubernetes plugin , or just land the job on a node that has kubeconfig and kubectl configured.

Comment: you can find all those things on google search how to integrate jenkins with github , how to use jenkins to deploy to kubernetes etc etc

Comment: Awesome :) Final question: How would you recommend moving an application from one cluster to another.. This I tried to find on Google as welll but unfortunately there arent many good tutorials :(

Comment: I had read about it from an SRE blog , the tool they used is https://github.com/heptio/velero

Comment: Thanks I will definitely check it out :) Is it possible to accomplish this target using something like Helm as well? Im thinking of reading everything and trying to pick the best one..

Comment: Helm is just templating your kubernetes deployment manifests , it can be useful if you are a software provider and there are millions of users who are going to deploy it in different configurations and environments

Comment: https://blog.kubernauts.io/backup-and-restore-of-kubernetes-applications-using-heptios-velero-with-restic-and-rook-ceph-as-2e8df15b1487

Comment: Awesome... Was watching a tutorial on Velero.. Looks good so far. Will try. Thanks a bunch for your help, man. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you are trying to implement GitOps, my advice is to review this article where you can start to figure out a little bit more about the components you need.

https://www.weave.works/blog/managing-helm-releases-the-gitops-way

Basically, you need to implement your own helm charts for your custom services and manage it using flux, I recommend to use a different repository per environment and leave flux to manage the deployment to each environment based on the state of the master branch on the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Look at spinnaker for continuous delivery. After the image is built and pushed to registry, have a web hook in spinnaker trigger a deployment to required kubernetes cluster. Spinnaker works well with kubernetes and you definitely should try it out