# How to deploy to a (local) Kubernetes cluster using Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, continuous-deployment

This question is somewhat related to one of [my previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57043048/best-practices-when-implementing-ci-cd-pipeline-using-github-jenkins-kubernetes) as in it gives a clearer idea on what I am trying to achieve.. This question is about an issue I ran into when trying to achieve the task in that previous question...

I am trying to test if my `kubectl` works from within the Jenkins container. When I start up my Jenkins container I use the following command:

```
docker run \ 
    -v /home/student/Desktop/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home \
    -v $(which kubectl):/usr/local/bin/kubectl \ #bind docker host binary to docker container binary
    -v ~/.kube:/home/jenkins/.kube \ #docker host kube config file stored in /.kube directory. Binding this to $HOME/.kube in the docker container
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \ 
    -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -v ~/.kube:/home/root/.kube \ 
    --group-add 998 
    -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 
    -d --name jenkins jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

The container starts up and I can login/create jobs/run pipeline scripts all no issue.

I created a pipeline script just to check if I can access my cluster like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Kubernetes test') {
            steps {
                sh "kubectl cluster-info"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running this job, it fails with the following error:

```
+ kubectl cluster-info // this is the step

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "services"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not getting why there is:

`-v $(which kubectl):/usr/local/bin/kubectl -v ~/.kube:/home/jenkins/.kube`

`/usr/local/bin/kubectl` is a kubectl binary and `~/.kube:/home/jenkins/.kube` should be the location where the kubectl binary looks for the cluster context file i.e. `kubeconfig`. First, you should make sure that the `kubeconfig` is mounted to the container at `/home/jenkins/.kube` and is accessible to `kubectl` binary. After appropriate volume mounts, you can verify by creating a session in the jenkins container with `docker container exec -it jenkins /bin/bash` and test with `kubectl get svc`. Make sure you have `KUBECONFIG` env var set in the session with:

```
export KUBECONFIG=/home/jenkins/.kube/kubeconfig
```

Before you run the verification test and

```
withEnv(["KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/kubeconfig"]) {
// Your stuff here
}
```

In your pipeline code. If it works with the session, it should work in the pipeline as well.

I would personally recommend to create a custom Docker image for Jenkins which will contain `kubectl` binary and other utilities necessary (such as `aws-iam-authenticator` for AWS EKS IAM-based authentication) for working with Kubernetes cluster. This creates isolation between your host system binaries and your Jenkins binaries.

Below is the `Dockerfile` I'm using which contains, `helm`, `kubectl` and `aws-iam-authenticator`.

```
# This Dockerfile contains Helm, Docker client-only, aws-iam-authenticator, kubectl with Jenkins LTS.

FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
USER root

ENV VERSION v2.9.1
ENV FILENAME helm-${VERSION}-linux-amd64.tar.gz
ENV HELM_URL https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-helm/${FILENAME}
ENV KUBE_LATEST_VERSION="v1.11.0"

# Install the latest Docker CE binaries
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install apt-transport-https \
      ca-certificates \
      curl \
      gnupg2 \
      software-properties-common && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID")/gpg > /tmp/dkey; apt-key add /tmp/dkey && \
    add-apt-repository \
      "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/$(. /etc/os-release; echo "$ID") \
      $(lsb_release -cs) \
      stable" && \
   apt-get update && \
   apt-get -y install docker-ce \
   && curl -o /tmp/$FILENAME ${HELM_URL} \
   && tar -zxvf /tmp/${FILENAME} -C /tmp \
   && mv /tmp/linux-amd64/helm /bin/helm \
   && rm -rf /tmp/linux-amd64/helm \
   && curl -L https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/${KUBE_LATEST_VERSION}/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl -o /usr/local/bin/kubectl \
   && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kubectl \
   && curl -L https://amazon-eks.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.11.5/2018-12-06/bin/linux/amd64/aws-iam-authenticator -o /usr/local/bin/aws-iam-authenticator \
   && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/aws-iam-authenticator
```

Comment: Hi.. I edited my question to add comments explaining the requested lines.. Please check. Basically, I tried to make the `kubectl` binary of the docker host available to the Jenkins container and I bound the `KUBECONFIG` directory of the docker host to the Jenkins container.. Also, thanks a lot for your custom Jenkins Dockerfile... I tried to make one of my own and it didnt work.. Your Dockerifle helped me find the mistake in it :)

Comment: Use the above `Dockerfile` to build a custom image with `kubectl` pre-installed or create a session inside the container and test `kubectl` as described in the answer. If it works with the session, it should work in the pipeline.

Comment: thanks a lot. I will try now and see.. How do you transfer the conf file in the docker host to the Jenkins container?

Comment: Using volumes ` -v "/home/<user>/.kube:/root/.kube"`

Answer (score 0):

[Kubernetes fails inside jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68187633/kubernetes-fails-inside-jenkins-pipeline?noredirect=1#comment120524814_68187633) this was my solution for jenkins installed locally on a windows machine.