# Kubernetes fails inside jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to run kubectl commands inside jenkins pipeline but they are failing. Outside in powershell window they work fine but in the pipeline, they show this when doing:

```
kubectl cluster-info --v=99
```

[image]

I've tried adding --token $TOKEN (jwt generated) following some other thread's recommendation but didn't work. Anyone know why this is happening and any way to bypass it? All these commands work fine when ran outside the jenkins pipeline.

Comment: Can you replace image with the text ?

Comment: Can you try to set kubectl config before running kubectl command? This is an authentication issue. Kubernetes says "I don't know someone as Jenkins"

Comment: You should set the kubeconfig with the environment directive and a secret file credentials value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was jenkins actually uses a different home directory and so even if your kubectl work in command line, it won't run if jenkins runs it from the pipeline as it doesn't have access to the credentials from the user directory.

So find your .kube config folder, usually in C:/users/ and then copy and paste that folder in the $JENKINS_HOME directory. The jenkins home directory can vary depending on how you installed it (for windows installers, it gets put in an obscure location inside System32). Once done, then jenkins will have access to the same certificates you use natively to run kubectl commands and it will have full access.